# How can I most efficiently launch myself through my car's windshield?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the challenges in the Saintsbook is "Windshield Cannon" - I have to launch myself through the windshields of cars until I've met a certain distance requirement.

I can't seem to figure out what causes me to fly through the windshield though.  I found a sports car and fully upgraded it, then sent it full bore into the side of a guard rail.  I didn't fly out.  However, on my way to reset, I accidentally hit a nearby electrical pole at a much lower speed and I went flying.

How can I guarantee I'll go flying?  Is there any easy way to max out this challenge?

Comment: [Suicide is never an option.](http://www.metanoia.org/suicide/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trick to this seems to be to do it while playing Insurance Fraud, where everyone is driving faster and you have a much higher chance of flying through the windshield on impact:

You can safely cancel the insurance fraud activity before it ends and you'll keep any windshield cannon distance you got.  I'm not sure if letting time expire does the same thing, but I'd assume so.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it's a matter of speed and impact force, which boils down to you in a fast car driving fast into the front of another fast moving car.

Comment: Not just that, though: you also have to have less momentum than the car you hit, otherwise you just send them through the windshield. Fun to watch, but not helpful for the challenge.