# What's the easiest way to maximize profits from Insurance Fraud?

Tags: saints-row-the-third, saints-row-2

Insurance Fraud is one of the side activities in Saints Row 3, and it plays extremely similarly to the way it did in Saints Row 2.  I'm planning on using it in SR3 to get the [Windshield Cannon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38508/how-can-i-most-efficiently-launch-myself-through-my-cars-windshield) challenge, but that means that I'm going to have to gain money in Insurance Fraud very quickly to make up for the time I spend goofing around and flying through windshields.

What's the best strategy for playing Insurance Fraud?

Comment: This game inspires the best question titles.

Comment: @Brant, Naming these questions is half the fun in posting them :)

Comment: This should be in money.stackexchange.com too :)

Comment: @M28: But then it might be closed as "not constructive".  ;)

Comment: @Jeff, indeed, if there's one thing you could say about insurance fraud, it's definitely "de-structive"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trick I've always used (this worked in SR2 as well as SR3) is as follows:

- Start the mission
- Get to the nearest highway
- Stand in the shoulder until you see a car coming (ideally a long line of cars, or a large truck)
- When the car is getting close, run into the street and towards the hood of the car.
- Jump and hit the ragdoll button (in SR3, don't use your "sprint" for this, or you'll do a dive roll instead of a jump)
- If there are more cars behind the one you hit, try to aim yourself at another car while in midair.

When your adrenaline maxes out, try to "surf" down the highway by hitting the front of a large truck, and then guide yourself in midair so that you hit it again as you're coming down.

Cars appear to be more plentiful and drive faster on the highway, although this has been adjusted in SR3, so smaller streets are a more viable option.  If you're in the road, they may slow down (this was much worse in SR2), which reduces the chances they will hit you hard enough to give good cash.  Thus, stay out of the road unless you're just about to get hit.

Any road that has a low overhang (some of the between island bridges, for instance) are particularly bad for doing this.  Your height will be severely limited.  If you find yourself in an area with a low ceiling, do what you can to get out from underneath it.

In general, the more cars you hit in one fall, the better.  Each car hit doubles your score for the hit, as well as adding a decent amount to the money counter.  The cars don't have to be unique; you can bounce back and forth between 2 cars, and it will continue to count towards your multiplier.

If you're in adrenaline mode and the meter is running low, you can recharge your adrenaline if you "finish" a large hit before you run out.  Adrenaline mode also doubles your score for any hits that finish while its active, so finishing a hit before it runs out is better than landing afterwards, if you have a choice.

Finally, if you're playing with a partner, one of you may want to hang out in the "extra adrenaline" zones.  The highway is a much better place to get massive hits, but having your adrenaline maxed out is enough of a benefit to make it worthwhile if you have two people.

Comment: In my experience, it really works fine on any straight stretch of road ping-ponging yourself between oncoming cars from each direction.  They usually don't slow down so will have plenty of speed.  Of course, it's best to jump in front of them at the very last second or they _may_ stop.

Comment: @Jeff, I think they adjusted the mechanics a bit in SR3.  I'll agree that it seems like people in Insurance Fraud are going at highway speeds regardless of the street, but the highways always seem to have more cars.  That just might be my perception though.  I will say that having something overhead (ie, an elevated train track or highway) is a big disadvantage if you're picking a street to work with.

Comment: I haven't played SR2 (or 1) so I don't have any other basis for comparison.  I just know that there will be a decent amount of cars on the straight and narrow (one lane) roads since they can't spread out much.  I tended to hang around the bonus zones hoping for trucks to come by so they could take me places.  :)

Comment: A highway is better than an intersection because there aren't any lights to slow down careful drivers and because there is traffic coming from just two directions, not four (or more). More directions means more possibility of being hit when you're not ready for it and more chances that cars will go by when you can't take advantage of them.

Comment: I can confirm the highway works. I was stuck on Insurance Fraud - Hard, read the above answer and tried it. I found a ramp that brought the cars downward and I believe my lowest cash gain was around 18,000. You don't even have to get to the top, I couldn't make it up halfway without being hit by a speeding car.

Comment: I found out this evening that, when in coop mode, one player running over the other counts for damage.  We weren't able to get a system to work as well as I'd hoped, but I think the idea has potential if we had been using better teamwork

Answer (score 6):

To add to your great answer, here's some more tips that I have.

Except for the start of the activity or want to get to another place on the map, stay out of cars and say on foot.  It's a lot harder to get thrown out of it than it is to jump in front of a moving vehicle.  When you're going to bail on the vehicle you have, don't leave your car on the road potentially blocking other cars, leave it on the sidewalk or something.

Look for the long straight and narrow roads where "trains" of cars can be on the road.  You want to make it easier to hit multiple cars at once and the narrower the road, the less spread out the cars will be.

When you take a hit from a vehicle, *always* move in the direction of the vehicle.  You have some air control and the longer you can stay with the vehicle means more opportunities to keep getting hit by the same vehicle.  If it somehow manages to get away from you, you can almost always bet there's another one following behind.

As you approach an intersection, consider moving toward oncoming traffic when they come by.  There's a chance that the vehicles reaching it will want to stop or slow down.  Vehicles coming out of it will likely be speeding away from it.

Comment: Leaving your car in the intersection can cause several problems: it blocks traffic itself, it'll slow down the conscientious drivers (some drivers won't care, but many do stop for red lights and such), and it can even trigger an argument between drivers, or worse, an incident with police. Whether or not you're involved, having angry police around means cars going in directions other than towards you, and that's a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a little cheat. Although it does take a long time to make money this way, if you're stuck on an Insurance Fraud activity, then all you have to do is when there is a couple of seconds left on the clock, keep tapping

> <kbd>LT</kbd><kbd>RT</kbd><kbd>LT</kbd><kbd>RT</kbd>

and so on. You keep gaining money while the clock says that it should end. I only know that this works for sure on the 360; I'm unsure if it works on the PS3 and PC, but if it does work on the PS3, it would be

> <kbd>R2</kbd><kbd>L2</kbd><kbd>R2</kbd><kbd>L2</kbd>

and so on.