# If a takeover is used in co-op, does the second player also get the activities completed?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In *Saints Row the Third* if player one uses a city takeover (cell phone upgrade, STAG, etc) to secure a district will player two also get all activities in the district marked as complete? I have 2 hard Insurance Fraud activities left and am hoping I can join someone's game when they go to use a takeover perk to get those done. I hate the Insurance Fraud activity.

Comment: What platform?  If you are stuck on the 360, maybe I can help :)

Comment: @agent86 I'm on the 360.

Comment: @agent86 I'm playing SR3 now. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since city takeover percentage is calculated separately, I don't believe this is the case.  I seem to remember my partner using one of these during one of our sessions, and I don't believe I got credit for it.  I got the phone call from the homie congratulating me on the district being cleared, but I didn't get credit for any unfinished activities.

If you're having issues with Insurance Fraud, have you read the question/answer about it on the site?  It's a pretty easy diversion once you know the tricks:

[What's the easiest way to maximize profits from Insurance Fraud?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39176/whats-the-easiest-way-to-maximize-profits-from-insurance-fraud)

Comment: I've read that thread. Still, it's very hard.