# Do I need to gain weight in order to be a better windshield cannoneer?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

While driving around to get the windshield cannon achievement, I 'accidentally' crashed head on with another car.  To my surprise, I wasn't launched from my car but the other driver was launched from her car.  Since we were driving identical cars, the only difference I could tell was that the other driver was chubbier than me.

This leads to my question, does putting on weight have any effect on the chance and distance for a windshield cannoneer?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't because the other driver was moving faster than you? That would be my first guess rather than the weight difference

Comment: @Lawton actually I was probably going much faster than her, since most drivers don't go blazing down the wrong lane of the highway at insane speeds...

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38508/42984

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windshied canon probablilty is derived from the magnitude of decelaration and the strength of the car you are in, **not the mass of the character**. (hit hard stuff fast with soft stuff)

this means that upgraded cars reduce the risk of canoning. Enjoy XD

Comment: @One-One In-game mass is **never changed**, even after tubbing up a plastic surgeon. Also your character cannot gain weight through play. However, it is possible change the characters mass through modding.